# Python: How to find input of function given an output (i.e. "Goal Seek" functionality in excel)

Tags: python, optimization

I have a function like so:

```
def function(length, period, x, y, z): 
     lst = []
     for i in range(length):         
          answer = x / ((1 + (x + y)/12))**period)
          lst.append(answer)
     final_answer = sum(lst)
     return final_answer
```

I know the following variables: final_answer, length, period, x and z. I do not know y. Is there an easy way to optimize for y? I have tried a couple different methods to no avail. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Code doesn't run, unbalanced parantheses here ```answer = x / ((1 + (x + y)/12))**period)```. If you can please also provide sample input values for the function.

Comment: maybe first try to resolve it on paper - try to reverse calculations. If you use `print()` in current code then you sould see that `answer` in every loop has the same value (or you made mistake  in code) and you could calculate `answer` only once and next get `final_answer = answer * length` - so first step could be `answer = final_answer/length`, next `answer * x  = ((1 + (x + y)/12))**period`, if I'm now wrong `(answer * x)**(1/period)  = (1 + (x + y)/12)`, next `(answer * x)**(1/period) - 1 = (x + y)/12`, next `((answer * x)**(1/period) - 1)*12 = (x + y)`, and next  `y = ... - x`